# Android BitmapRegionDecoder Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

It seems that BitmapRegionDecoder has a memory leak. If I run the code bellow, I can see increase in native memory usage on the device. Eventually the application will die due to the crash, as the Android OS will kill it due to the lack of free memory:

```
public void doClick(View v) {

    String bitmapFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/Wallpaper Images/-398300536.jpg";
    BitmapRegionDecoder dec;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(bitmapFileName);
            dec = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);

            // I am not even doing anything with bitmap region decoder!

            is.close();
            dec.recycle();
            System.gc();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Running `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` will report the following **prior** executing the code above (see 3273 kB of native allocations):

```
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 63276459 Realtime: 469577132

** MEMINFO in pid 27844 [com.example.test] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:     3284     5379      N/A     8663
       allocated:     3273     2831      N/A     6104
            free:       10     2548      N/A     2558
           (Pss):      600      779     2248     3627
  (shared dirty):       56     1256     5164     6476
    (priv dirty):      540       44     1036     1620

 Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
   Local Binders:        5    Proxy Binders:       10
Death Recipients:        0
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
               heap:        0         MEMORY_USED:        0
 PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0         MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```

Running `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` **after** executed code above reports **12678kB of allocated native memory!**

```
 Applications Memory Usage (kB):
 Uptime: 63281361 Realtime: 469582034

 ** MEMINFO in pid 27844 [com.example.test] **
                     native   dalvik    other    total
             size:    12972     5379      N/A    18351
        allocated:    12678     2792      N/A    15470
             free:       33     2587      N/A     2620
            (Pss):      665      871    12411    13947
   (shared dirty):       56     1256     5560     6872
     (priv dirty):      612       48    10820    11480

  Objects
            Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
      AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
           Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
    Local Binders:        5    Proxy Binders:       11
 Death Recipients:        1
  OpenSSL Sockets:        0

  SQL
                heap:        0         MEMORY_USED:        0
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0         MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```

The problem seems to be always reproducible on 2.3.5 and 4.1.2 Android (physical devices). The problem is also always reproducible on the Android emulator (I tried Android 2.3.3). I haven't tried other versions of Android, but my guess is that the problem is the same on other versions too.

Am I doing something wrong, or does `recycle()` method of BitmapRegionDecoder simply doesn't work?

How could I avoid this problem?

Comment: Hi AZX, Facing the same issue. Did you found any solution for the same.? If you could help me.